# PGF bar chart - how to fill and draw with one command?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I produce the following chart:
[image]

Right now, to make sure that the outline and fill of the bar are in red, I do:

`\addplot [red, fill = red, ybar]...`

If I omit the `fill = red`, the graph is not filled.
If I omit the `draw = red`, the outline is black.
So, it seems like I need both commands.

If you're producing many charts, it can get annoying to have to change colours in two places. Is there a way to set the `draw` and `fill` with a single command? I tried `filldraw` but to no avail.

---

MWE to produce the above and play with:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
    date, yoy
    1Q19, 4
    2Q19, 3
    3Q19, 2
    4Q19, 3
    1Q20, 4.5
}\hchartone

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=left,
enlarge x limits={0.1},
xtick=data,
xticklabels from table={\hchartone}{date}, 
table/x expr = \coordindex,       
]
\addplot [red, fill = red, ybar] table [y=yoy]  {\hchartone};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\addplot [red,fill, ybar] table [y=yoy]  {\hchartone};` is enough, you do not have to say `fill=red` after `red`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to say

```
\addplot [red,fill, ybar] table [y=yoy] {\hchartone};
```

to get the result. If the question is whether or not one can coin a `filldraw` key, the answer is affirmative.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
    date, yoy
    1Q19, 4
    2Q19, 3
    3Q19, 2
    4Q19, 3
    1Q20, 4.5
}\hchartone

\begin{tikzpicture}[filldraw/.style={draw=#1,fill=#1},filldraw/.default=black]
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=left,
enlarge x limits={0.1},
xtick=data,
xticklabels from table={\hchartone}{date}, 
table/x expr = \coordindex,       
]
\addplot [filldraw=red, ybar] table [y=yoy]  {\hchartone};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the comment pointing out my complete fubar-ing of a simple command, and this answer which taught me a new technique!

Comment: @TheveshTheva You're welcome!